# Add Glare to Equirectangular Panorama Without Stitching Issues

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, panoramic

I made an equirectangular panorama in blender, and I added a glare node to emulate glow on the objects. When I view the rendered image, the glow does not stitch properly. Is there a way to fix this, or add the glow in a way that will allow the image to stitch properly?

[image: glare node]
[image: stitching problem]
You can see that glow is cut off when the image is stitched. To combat this problem, some of the glow should be visible on the other side of the image, as indicated below...
[image: Missing glow]

Comment: I know that the blur function recently had a boundary function included so that it could blur outside of an image's boundaries. I don't think that the same occurred to glow. The Translate Node does have a wrap function so that when you slide the image left to right it will wrap around the other side. Perhaps with masks you could perform the glow twice then (with and without translate wrap) then composite them together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As 3pointedit suggested in the comments, you can use the Translate node to make it seamless:

[image: seamless glare]

I set the Mix to 1 in the Glare nodes so they output only the glare, which I mix using Lighten.